# adding an on_release action to a kivy button

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to refactor [the last code sample](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/firstwidget.html) so that the `Button` is actually its own class with an `on_release` action. But my code is failing.

I want to not only refactor it (per my attempt below) but I also need to set the text of the `Button` to "Clear"

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        userdata = touch.ud
        userdata['color'] = c = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*c, mode='hsv')
            d = 30
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d/2, touch.y - d/2), size=(d, d))
            userdata['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class ClearButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, paint_widget):
        self.paint_widget=paint_widget

    def on_release(self, button):
        self.paint_widget.canvas.clear()

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = ClearButton(painter)
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)

        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 11):

Without subclassing, you could just do:

```
class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    # ... put your previous methods here
    def clear_canvas(self, *largs):
        self.canvas.clear()

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        cleanbtn.bind(on_release=self.painter.clear_canvas)
        root.add_widget(painter)
        root.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return root
```

With subclassing, i would prefer to go with Kv langage:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<ClearButton>:
    text: "Clear"
    on_release: app.painter.canvas.clear()
''')

class ClearButton(Button):
    pass

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = ClearButton()
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent
```